# How to stop Python 3 printing none

Tags: python

how do I stop this from printing none at the end. Or is it inevitable?

```
x = int(input("Please enter a number to print up to."))
def print_upto(x):
for y in range(1,x+1):
    print(y)
print(print_upto(x))
```

Many thanks.

Comment: is that your indentation? and if your function is printing you don't need to call `print(print_upto(x))` just `print_upto(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
print(print_upto(x))
```

on the last line, just do,

```
print_upto(x)`
```

thats it, and it will work fine.

Comment: by default your function returns `None` unless you are returning something, which you are not, so the `print` statement outputs an extra line to print `None` as the return value of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not return any value, it just `print` it. So return value is `None`. And when you `print(print_upto(x))` it's equal to `print(None)`

And if you want to see printed values you just need to call `print_upto(x)` without any `print()`